# Add elements from a list to multiple other nested lists

Tags: r, list

I have a list of lists, as follows:

```
my_list = list(list(a=1,b=2),list(a=1,b=2),list(a=1,b=2))
```

I have a vector b_new, the length of which is exactly the same as `length(my_list)`:

```
b_new = c(3,4,5)
```

I would like to overwrite the b-elements of my_list with the values in b sequentially, so the expected output is:

```
my_list = list(list(a=1,b=3),list(a=1,b=4),list(a=1,b=5))
```

I could obviously do this in a for loop:

```
for(i in 1:length(b_new))
{
  my_list[[i]]$b=b_new[i]
}
```

but I wonder if there is a way of doing this without a for loop, for example using mapply?

Comment: I wonder how the `purrr` solution via its `map*` functions would be. Maybe I will give it a shot later on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still a loop really, but the following will do it:

```
Map(`[<-`, my_list, "b", b_new)
# or more pleasantly named:
Map(replace, my_list, "b", b_new)

str(Map(`[<-`, my_list, "b", b_new))
#List of 3
# $ :List of 2
#  ..$ a: num 1
#  ..$ b: num 3
# $ :List of 2
#  ..$ a: num 1
#  ..$ b: num 4
# $ :List of 2
#  ..$ a: num 1
#  ..$ b: num 5
```

Comment: Thanks, maybe not more efficient(?), but it looks a lot cleaner. I am trying to understand the statement, but when I  type `help(Map)`, I see: `Map(f, ...)`, where ... are vectors. Would you care to explain how the "b" in your statement works?

Comment: @florian this essentially expands to doing listitem["b"] <- b_newitem over and over. The "b" in the call is just recycled over and over while map works through the other 2 parts.